# Why do people say "I did do" instead of just "I did"?

Tags: verbs, emphasis, do-support

I saw a sentence like this:

> So I did do Spanish for four years.

I can't understand why it's not just "I did".

Comment: It is part of a contrastive 'rebuttal' construction. If you say | *I did do Spanish for four years*, it emphatically contrasts with the idea that you didn't do Spanish, or didn't do it for very long.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. That's right. The *do/did* in English here is just like using the emphatic *sí* particle in Spanish:  *“¿Entonces no estudiaste ningún idioma, verdad?” “Yo **sí** hice castellano durante cuatro años.”*  Using an emphatic *do/did* like this is especially useful in a retort, like when you're negating a previous negative with a positive, the same way you do with *mais si* in French, *sondern* in German, and *sino* in Spanish.

Comment: It seems to me that this construction is using "do Spanish" as a phrasal verb, meaning "study Spanish" or perhaps "take courses in Spanish". If someone said: "I did study Spanish for two years" would you think it odd?

Comment: @DavidSiegel Yes, it's marked.

Answer (score 1):

Like most things, it all depends upon context.

> What did you do at university?
> I did Spanish for four years.

> I heard you didn't complete your four-year Spanish course.
> No, I *did* do Spanish for four years.

In the first example you are simply stating a fact.
You might even stress the "four" to emphasize its significance.

In the second example you are affirming or denying a fact.

---

Most of the confusion here is because "did" and "do" happen to be forms of the same word.

If the words were different:

> I *ran* in the Boston Marathon last year.
> I *did run* in the Boston Marathon last year.

the different meanings would be obvious: a statement of fact, and a denial of an accusation.